# What is the fastest way to move files?

Tags: nautilus

I have a large folder around 6.6GB, it contains about 450000 files. I copy it from one partition to another. It writes that 6 hours left though it has been running for 3 hours now. Average transfer speed is 200kb/s. Is there a better way for file transferring?

Comment: Are you copying by dragging and dropping? Or from terminal? Also check here: http://superuser.com/questions/488333/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-move-a-million-images-from-one-directory-to-another

Comment: None can beat a command line execution. I'd say; make a use of `mv` command. But it is better if you copy first then remove the files from source directory (to be on the safe side).

Comment: Is the other partition an NTFS drive or a USB drive? Those would reduce the speed dramaticly.

Comment: @DanJohansen
No, it's not NTFS, it's Ext4.

Comment: @jmunsch
from right click context menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Do you need to keep permissions?
- Do you want to continue rather than restart if the copy process is interrupted?

Why not use `rsync -a /source/ /destination/` then?

Comment: Agreed; rsync will be a lot quicker than mv. And doing the whole dir is best too; avoid wildcards cuz they'll get expanded (=slow)

Comment: Well for the first point I'd say compressing the whole directory using `tar` will retain its permission too if I'm not mistaken. But kudos for the second point though. :)

Comment: 16:46 transfer just started...

Comment: Just finished 18:00. It took about 1:45h with `rsync` is it ok?

Comment: @kenn It was much faster than the method in your question, so I'd say it is good enough :)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha
that's right, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ultracopier`](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/powerful-file-copy-move-utility-ubuntu-linux-ultracopier/).Run the below command to install `ultracopier` package,

Daily version,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultracopier/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ultracopier
```

For stable version,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultracopier/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ultracopier
```

Comment: Ultracopier is not in repo

Comment: Enable the universe repository,update them `sudo apt-get update` then run `sudo apt-get install ultracopier`.

Comment: I enabled that repository still no luck

Comment: @kenn It seems that ultracopier went out of the repo in 13.04 and in again in 13.10.

Comment: I checked out its site, they removed Linux source code, I wonder why. It's not working well in Linux?